# unique_ptr ownership semantics

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, ownership-semantics

Perhaps I was trying to be too generic. (Original question below) Concretely, I have some dependency `Dep` of a class `Foo`. I also have a class `MockDep` and am defining a class `TestFoo`. Here is its constructor I tried to write:

```
TestFoo(unique_ptr<MockDep> dep) : Foo(std::move(dep)), mock_dep_(dep.get()) {}
```

And `Foo`'s constructor looks like:

```
Foo(unique_ptr<Dep> dep) : dep_(dep) {}
```

`mock_dep_` is delcared in `TestFoo` as `MockDep* mock_dep_`, and `dep_` is declared in `Foo` as `unique_ptr<Dep> dep_`. How can I get `mock_dep_` to contain `dep_`'s address? (as the above doesn't work since `std::move(dep)` nulls out `dep`.)

---

**Original post:**

I have an object of type `Foo` that I'm to pass to a different object of type `OtherObject` which claims ownership of it, but as a pointer to its base class. However, I want to grab a pointer to the child object that I can use to reference it. I wrote something like:

```
Foo(std::unique_ptr<Child> thing) :
    OtherObject(std::move(thing)), child_(thing.get()) {}

OtherObject(std::unique_ptr<Base> thing, ...) { ... }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, as the `std::move(thing)` seems to null out the pointer that returns from `thing.get()` later.

I can change `Foo`'s parameter to be of type `Child*` instead of `unique_ptr<Child>`, but I'd prefer to be able to do the latter as it explicitly documents the ownership semantics.

What's the most appropriate (or failing that, unobtrusive) way of resolving this?

**edit**: `Foo` and `OtherObject` are both meant to be classes whose constructors I'm defining.

Comment: What's `OtherObject`? AFAIK it can't be a function in that context.

Comment: @Jefffrey I'm unsure what confusion remains -- I rewrote the post to refer more directly to my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "dependency" ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb "dependency" in the sense of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) -- basically just some object that the class needs to use

Answer (score 6):

You may use:

```
Foo(std::unique_ptr<Child> thing) :
    OtherObject(std::move(thing)),
    child_(OtherObject.getChildPtr()) /* one accessor to get the pointer. */
{}
```

If base object `OtherObject` doesn't provide an accessor to the pointer, you may delegate the constructor to an other constructor, something like:

```
class Foo: public OtherObject
{
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Child> thing) : Foo(thing, thing.get()) {}

private:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Child>& thing, Child* child) :
        OtherObject(std::move(thing)),
        child_(child)
    {}
private:
    Child* child_;
};
```

A third solution would be to change the order between `OtherObject` and `child_` (to have `child_` before) by introducing an other derivation:

```
class ChildPtr
{
public:
    ChildPtr(Child* child) : child_(child) {}

    Child* child_;
};

class Foo: private ChildPtr, public OtherObject
{
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Child> thing) :
        ChildPtr(thing.get()),
        OtherObject(std::move(thing))
    {}
};
```

Comment: `OtherObject` is a base class according to OP.

Comment: `OtherObject` is meant to be some arbitrary type, not a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Using the terminology of my edited post, I was wanting to avoid modifying `Foo` to provide a getter (mostly because it would require a static_cast), but the other solution isn't too attractive either, so I might just go with the casting accessor.

Comment: @alecb: I have added an other alternative which may fit better with your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Generally what happens is described in the standard as:

> §17.6.5.15.1 **Moved-from state of library types** [lib.types.movedfrom]
>
> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

The standard actually specifically describe the behavior of `std::unique_ptr` in:

> §20.8.1.4 **Class template unique_ptr** [unique.ptr]
>
> Additionally, `u` can, upon request, transfer ownership to another unique pointer `u2`. Upon completion of such a transfer, the following postconditions hold:
>
> - u2.p is equal to the pre-transfer u.p,
> - u.p is equal to nullptr, and
> - if the pre-transfer u.d maintained state, such state has been transferred to u2.d.

Specifically, `dep`, after the construction of the `Foo` sub-object at:

```
Foo(std::move(dep))
```

is a `nullptr`.

Moreover if `dep` was still a valid pointer, `Foo(std::move(dep))` would have copied `dep`, which doesn't make sense for `std::unique_ptr`'s semantic (as it is non-copyable).

What you want to do is let a reference to the pointed object, with the due considerations of the case (for example, can the unique_ptr be `nullpt`? etc..), in `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(unique_ptr<Dep> dep) : dep_(dep) {}
    const Dep& get_dep() const { return *dep_; }
    Dep& get_dep()             { return *dep_; }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Dep> dep_;
};
```

and then simply construct the `TestFoo` object as:

```
TestFoo(unique_ptr<MockDep> dep) : Foo(std::move(dep)) {}
```

Comment: I believe `unique_ptr` specifically guarantees it's null'ed out though?